# Can you asymptotically analyze C libraries?

Tags: c, complexity-theory, glibc, musl

For example, I have two C libraries: musl and glibc. For my situation, I need speed, thus I want to use the library that would "run the fastest". Would this involve cataloging the time and space complexity of each function per library? Is there an objective way to determine which library would have a worst lower time and space complexity?

Comment: Big-O complexity does not imply the actual speed for your specific problem.

Comment: It's not about the wording, my point that you might want to profile each library for your specific use-cases. Lower complexity algorithms might perform better for bigger inputs, but perform poorer than "worse" in terms of big-O ones for smaller inputs

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah ok. I have already profiled them, is that the only way to approach this problem?

Comment: No, you can surely examine the algorithms used in each library if these are open-source or well documented.  You can also try analyzing it as a black box too, by running with differently sized inputs and seeing how the runtime/memory consumption is scaling, but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: @Anm: Profiling cannot definitively tell you anything about asymptotic complexity, unless you profile for infinite time using every possible input.  At best it can give you some evidence to help make a guess, but the actual determination of the complexity can only be done by reading the code.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, but ultimately one cares about the run time, not the complexity, right? Unless you're reading the code to discover the worst-case complexity...

Comment: But yes, as Eugene points out, your question is self-contradictory.  In the title you ask about doing asymptotic analysis, and in the body you want to know which will run the fastest in practice, and those are not at all the same thing.  At best there is some loose correlation between them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Agreed, but complexity is what OP specifically asked about (perhaps misguidedly).

Comment: @NateEldredge Well yes, expected that for the blackbox. Perhaps I could permutate inputs upto an arbitrary big amount of iterations into corresponding functions of each lib with some controls set. Would it be safe to presume a trend could be seen when doing so?

Comment: @NateEldredge I want to find worst-case complexity as black cat pointed out, I will edit my question

Comment: Worst-case complexity is a purely mathematical concept.  In that sense, it is never "safe" to presume a trend; it's always possible to have a counterexample that appears to "trend" one way, but whose actual mathematical complexity is something else.  This kind of confusion between pure math and actual practice is what I find odd about your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determining the fastest library for you is done through *benchmarking*, meaning timing how long it takes with realistic samples.

Specifically, determining time and space complexity of an algorithm won't tell you how fast it is. It's a measure of how its performance scales.